# Orientation Property- Issue with VBA Pivot Table

Tags: excel, vba

```
Sub Pivot()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim ptField As PivotField
    Dim ptRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastCol As Long
    
    ' Set the worksheet where you want to create the pivot table
    Set ws = Sheets("Pivot1") ' Change "Sheet1" to your sheet name
    ws.Cells.Clear
    ' Define the data range for the pivot table
    Dim sheet_from As Worksheet
    Set sheet_from = ActiveSheet
    last_row = sheet_from.Range("A65336").End(xlUp).Row
    Set ptRange = sheet_from.Range("A2:v" & last_row)
    
    ' Create a pivot table on a new sheet or existing sheet
    Set pt = ws.Parent.PivotTableWizard(TableDestination:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                                         TableName:="PivotTable2")

    ' Add fields to the pivot table
    With pt
        ' Add fields to rows
        
        Set ptField = .PivotFields("DEALDATE")
        ptField.Orientation = xlRowField
        
        Set ptField = .PivotFields("SETTDATE")
        ptField.Orientation = xlRowField
        
        Set ptField = .PivotFields("SECID")
        ptField.Orientation = xlRowField
        
         Set ptField = .PivotFields("DEALNO")
        ptField.Orientation = xlRowField
        
        ' Add fields to values
        Set ptField = .PivotFields("PROCEEDAMT") ' Change "Amount" to your field name
        ptField.Orientation = xlDataField
        ptField.Function = xlSum ' You can change the function as needed (e.g., xlCount, xlAverage, etc.)
        
        
         With .DataPivotField
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With
    End With
    sheet_from.Activate
End Sub
```

Hi all- I understand a similar question has been asked but with different technicalities. I'm still new to vba for context, and has made a code for different worksheet yet it always return with an error 1004. Please help me understand what I did wrong and what can I do to fix it. Thank you.

Below is the code with the issue

```
with .DataPivotField
            .Orientation = xlColumnField
            .Position = 1
        End With
    End With
    sheet_from.Activate
End Sub
```

Tried changing the position and orientation, yet it kept on showing as an error

Comment: Instead of creating the PT in the SAME sheet, do it in a new one (define a sheet_to sheet). Also check if there really is data in column A, as it looks like you adapted a piece of code somewhere.

Comment: `ws` and `sheet_from` are two differents sheets for pvt and data source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- I'm not certain if this is the sole issue with your code, but there are two missing arguments in the PivotTableWizard method.

```vb
    Set ptRange = sheet_from.Range("A2:v" & last_row)
    
    ' Create a pivot table on a new sheet or existing sheet
    Set pt = ws.Parent.PivotTableWizard(SourceType:=xlDatabase, _
                SourceData:=ptRange, _
                TableDestination:=ws.Range("A1"), _
                TableName:="PivotTable2")
```